# Securing data sessions over WFC/JSON with Cookies or alternative methods

Tags: c#, json, wcf, wcf-security, setcookie

I have search for roughly 5 hours now on what would be the best method to "secure" data sessions/login sessions over WCF.

Some facts:

- The WCF code is in C# and will be hosted online for all to use (API)
- There will be a separate website that uses the API as a GUI for users
- It will also be consumed by the iPhone , Android and anything else I can think of
- The data will be sent using JSON
- Most Importantly: The API will be accessed over SSL

**Option 1 -**

I have been toying with using cookies to secure access to the API system. I know an easy way, yet crude, is to submit a request as if it was a HTTP request from a browser and use **Forms Authentication**. I would prefer to do this using only JSON and Cookies - assuming I go down that route.

**Option 2 -**

That being said about Cookies. I thought of another way to accomplish this, maybe it is a more secure way also? I would to pass an authentication (custom class) object through JSON along with the object(s) required for each call. Within this authentication object there would be two or more members:

1. SessionID: This would be a GUID which is stored in the API's database
2. HashValue: Possible a MD5 Hash, I haven't decided, that will be updated on each call

The idea of updating the HashValue on each successful call made to the API is so that the client's locally stored authentication object will be changed so that no spoofing could be carried out. At least I believe this, maybe I am wrong?

**Note:** This value would be generated server side, stored in the database and passed back to the client.

I am unsure which way to go. If option 2 would be a better way then away I go.

Only if Option 1 is the best then my issue here is I actually cannot find how to set the cookie in the WCF service on the API side. Any pointers?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantage of using Forms Authentication is that you then do not have to worry yourself with having the expertise of a security/cryptography professional.  You can use an already hardened way to securely manage a session.  Further, sticking with the HTTP protocol limits issues with firewalls as most places allow outgoing port 80 and 443 traffic.

Your option 2 is essentially doing the same thing as Forms Authentication yourself with a changing hash.  Normally having a changing value (either hash or unpredictable value) is called a nonce and is use with OAuth.

Consider the OAuth support out there as it is platform independent and there are also already written libraries out there for that.

But if it were me and I'm using C# and WCF, I'd stick with Forms Authentication and put my effort into into the actual logic in the API that is my particular expertise.

Comment: You don't foresee any issues using the forms method while using other devices/software languages? I'm curious that's all, I'm not saying you are wrong by any means. Additionally, if I went the oAuth way, same question.

Comment: I specifically meant I regards to programmatic access, apps etc and windows/apple software. I realise if I were to use a browser from any of them it wouldn't be an issue. I assume I can just store te CookieContainer for further use, the same as in C#?

Comment: Well after going the Forms Auth route I have hit numerous walls that I simply cannot get around. I am now going the second route I mentioned. I don't foresee any issues with this as of yet; all devices/software should be able to handle JSON.

Comment: I did not expect any problems with Form Authentication, since what is needed is the ability to store a cookie.  OAuth works primarily through the http headers and also should be platform independent.  I don't see any issues with your second option, it is just unfortunate you have to focus on what should be common security logic.  Good luck.

Comment: I agree, I shouldn't have spent as much time as I did. If I was to be honest; I'm not new to programming, windows or web, but I am new to webservice using WCF. In all honesty I reckon normal webservices may of done the trick but I've gone this far and learn't this much about WCF that I might as well carry on. While I had other walls I defeated, some I left to come back to but the last, well I couldn't be bothered to write a custom Membership Provider for MySQL, as is required in this project. Like you said, so much time on something simple so I trashed it and went JSON. Thanks for your help!

Comment: To say why, MySQL decided to create their Membership Provider an abstract sealed class, unlike the native SQL one in NET which can easily be inherited and would of had me leaping the wall :). Why MySQL? I have an image of SQL server being like a person wearing a 12inch padded suit trying to walk around as opposed to someone wearing a tshirt and shorts. To much bloat to do simple things; which is all I need it for, the database that is. Don;t get me wrong, I highly rate SQL server - just Msoft like having their stuff "bloaty"!